# SoftLayer blockstorage status

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to retrieve SoftLayer Block storages.

I am using the following URL:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account.json?objectMask=mask[iscsiNetworkStorage.volumeStatus]
```

from which I recieve JSON-data.

What I want to know is, if the ISCSI Storage status is `"ACTIVE"` or something similar.

Here is the JSON-data which is received:

```
"capacityGb":20
"volumeStatus":"PROVISION_COMPLETED"
"volumeStatus":{"createDate":"2016-02-02T00:49:19-06:00","message":"Volume Provisioning has completed.","scheduleId":null,"typeId":314,"volumeId":8904469}}
```

How do I get to know the status?

Answer (score 0):

The property used to know the `status of a Network storage volume` is `volumeStatus` , please see: [SoftLayer_Network_Storage datatypes](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Storage).

It seems when ‘volumeStatus’ value  is null, the item is “inactive”, otherwise if it has a value (“Volume Provisioning has completed.”), the item is "active".

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getIscsiNetworkStorage?objectMask=mask[username,volumeStatus]

Method: GET
```

**References:**

[SoftLayer_Account::getIscsiNetworkStorage](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getIscsiNetworkStorage)

Comment: I tried to URL. but, why volumeStatus looks likes event. because it have child elements as message, scheduleId,createDate. thanks

Comment: Sorry I tried to find an explanation for this behavior, but I'm not able to explain the reason of this. In some cases, the `item` displays just an string with value `PROVISION_COMPLETED` and in other cases the item has child elements. If this blocks you to perform your requests, please open a ticket in order the devs can provide more information about this (it seems to be a bug).